# Load Java script on load of a php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have the  following table which is supposed to be created on the  run of the  php function called getClinicregForm  , :

```
 <?php function getClinicregForm() {
    //get disease
        require_once("DbInterface.php");
        $dbi = new DbInterface();
        $con = $dbi->connect();
        $pr_name = $dbi->getProjectname($con);
        $county_name = $dbi->getCountyname($con);
        $pr_nameEdit = $dbi->editProjectname($con);
        $county_nameEdit = $dbi->editCountyname($con);
        ?>  
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            DataTables Advanced Tables
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Rendering engine</th>
                                            <th>Browser</th>
                                            <th>Platform(s)</th>
                                            <th>Engine version</th>
                                            <th>CSS grade</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                            <td>Trident</td>
                                            <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
                                            <td>Win 95+</td>
                                            <td class="center">4</td>
                                            <td class="center">X</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeX">
                                            <td>Tasman</td>
                                            <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
                                            <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
                                            <td class="center">-</td>
                                            <td class="center">X</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeC">
                                            <td>Tasman</td>
                                            <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
                                            <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
                                            <td class="center">1</td>
                                            <td class="center">C</td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <link href="template/assets/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <script src="template/assets/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
                <script src="template/assets/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
                <script>
                    var dTbles = jQuery.noConflict();
                    dTbles(document).ready(function () {
                        alert('found...');
                        dTbles('#dataTables-example').dataTable();
                    });
                </script>



            </div>
        </div>


        <?php
        $event = "Display of New Registration form";
        //log this event
        $dbi->dothelog($con, $_SESSION['username'], $event, "null");
    } ?>
```

How do I make the  javascript run on click/load/run of the  php function getClinicregForm() ?

Comment: You want to run **getClinicregForm()** on an event. right?

Comment: You have to use ajax

Comment: Yes , that's what I'm doing. Though how do I load the datatables once the table has been generated by running the function getClinicregForm ?  It should be generated the last thing.